# is it possible to activate hardware virtualization on a asus x51rlseries laptop?

Tags: virtualbox, asus-laptop

is it possible to activate hardware virtualization on a asus x51rlseries laptop?
I want to install a 64bit virtualbox on this laptop to run windows 8 and the hardware virtualization is a prerequisite for this

Comment: Welcome to superuser!  Consider adding your system specs and any other pertinent info to your question (including the complete model number of your Laptop) to help future readers.

Answer (score 1):

What CPU is in the unit?  Many CPUs do NOT support Hardware Virtualization.

Most versions of the X51rl shipped with the [Core 2 Duo T5450](http://ark.intel.com/products/30787/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-T5450-2M-Cache-1_66-GHz-667-MHz-FSB), which does NOT support Hardware Virtualization.

Comment: it has a duo T5250, can that one do it?

Comment: @david Why not just look it up at the Intel site provided in the answer? :) Spoiler alert - [No it doesn't support it](http://ark.intel.com/products/30786/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-T5250-2M-Cache-1_50-GHz-667-MHz-FSB).